Removing low ell modes from CMB map with HealPix
there are 2 approaches to remove the low ell modes from CMB map.

Having access to alms as alm;

    lmax = hp.Alm.getlmax(len(alm))
    ls, ms = hp.Alm.getlm(lmax)
    alm[ls < 10] = 0  #Removing first 10 ls
    isw_map_2 = hp.alm2map(alm, nside)




def remove_low_ell(map,ell,nside):
   alm = hp.map2alm(map,lmax=3*nside-1,mmax=3*nside-1)
   k = []
   for i in range(len(alm)):
       if i < ell+1:
           k.append(0.0)
       else:
           k.append(1.0)
   alm2=hp.almxfl(alm, k)
   map = hp.alm2map(alm2,nside)
   return map

They are effectively the same, but resulting map will be slightly different.
What do you recommend ?
I tried both methods above
